# How to execute servlet and return nothing?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to execute servlet and return nothing?
For example, if I do in servlet

```
try (OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream()) {
    out.write(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

that will download a file without extension.

And if comment the above code then servlet returns an empty page.

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/363918/java/execute-servlet-returning-page

Comment: If you print nothing into the response, you get empty page. What else would you expect / need? If you don't want to navigate away from the previous page, you probably need either a redirect or AJAX.